# in javaScript factory pattern i am not g undefined value

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, factory

```js
var peopleFactory = function(name, age, height) {
  var temp = {};
  this.name = name;
  this.age = age;
  this.height = height;
  temp.printPerson = function() {
    console.log(this.name + '' + this.age + '' + this.height);
    document.write(this.name + '' + this.age + '' + this.height);
  };
  return temp;
};
var person1 = peopleFactory('tanmay', 27, 5.11);
var person2 = peopleFactory('chinmay', 37, 5.12);
person1.printPerson();
person2.printPerson();
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read through the [help], in particular [_How do I ask a good question?_](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Do your research, [search](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. If you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help. Good luck!

Comment: `this.name = name;` should be `temp.name = name;`... and the other ones too.

Answer (score 0):

You should not be using `this` in your factory as it's a reference to the global object (unless you want to call your factory with the `new` keyword. But then, it wouldn't be a factory anymore).

Instead, you could be using another local object where you would store your object's private data. By doing that, your printPerson() function becomes a closure and can access data inside that local object and will be able to print it once it's invoked.

```js
var peopleFactory = function(name, age, height) {
  var temp = {}, instance = {};

  temp.name = name;
  temp.age = age;
  temp.height = height;
  instance.printPerson = function() {
    console.log(temp.name + ' ' + temp.age + ' ' + temp.height);
    document.write('<br/>' + temp.name + ' ' + temp.age + ' ' + temp.height);
  };
  return instance;
};
var person1 = peopleFactory('tanmay', 27, 5.11);
var person2 = peopleFactory('chinmay', 37, 5.12);
person1.printPerson();
person2.printPerson();
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but here you go. Just make it a class.

```js
class peopleFactory {
  constructor(name, age, height) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
    this.height = height;
  }
  printPerson() {
    return this.name + ' ' + this.age + ' ' + this.height;
  };
};
var person1 = new peopleFactory('tanmay', 27, 5.11);
console.log(person1.printPerson())
```